# Spring: How to set network connection timeout for chosen endpoints?

Tags: java, spring

I need to set connection timeout for chosen endpoints.
What's ways to do it?

Comment: show relevant code?

Comment: it may be any Spring project

Comment: you can have different ways to call endpoints in spring/java

Comment: great, I prefer to set it in application.yml

Answer (score 0):

use below key in application.properties file

```
server.connection-timeout=XXXX ( project- level applicable for all)
```

as you said you want different timeout for different endpoint url then create different  restTemplate bean for different endpoint-url:--

For Spring Boot >= 1.4

```
 @Configuration
 public class ExampleConfig {

    @Value("${url.timeout1})
    private String timeout1;

    @Value("${url.timeout2})
    private String timeout2;
                @Bean
                public RestTemplate restTemplate1(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder1) 
                {
                    return restTemplateBuilder1
                       .setConnectTimeout(Integer.parse(timeout1)).build();
                       
                }
            }

               @Bean
                public RestTemplate restTemplate2(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder2) 
                {
                    return restTemplateBuilder2
                       .setConnectTimeout(Integer.parse(timeout2)).build();
                       
                }
            }
```

Read timeout1/timeout2 from application.properties file or yaml file.

later you can make a endpoint call using restTemplate.

Hope, it should resolve your issue.

Comment: it shall apply timeout to all endpoints, I need for chosen only

Comment: yes, but I need to set connection timeout not for outcoming requests only, but and for incoming too

Comment: got it,  there are multiple way to do that, one of them i am writing above.

Comment: way with restTemplate shall work for outgoing requests, isn't it?

Comment: it will work. Moreover you can also set readTimeout n other thing also like proxy n all with restTemplate.

Comment: Also accept the any of the posted answer if you really help you . so that other people can easily get an idea.

Comment: but what about incoming requests?

Comment: what do you mean by incoming request again. dude listen...when you make a call  with your own request  connection timeout will take care. defenition :--------A connect timeout defines a time period in which our client should establish a connection with a target host.------ReadTimeout-- it defines a maximum time of inactivity between two data packets when waiting for the server's response.

Comment: I mean incoming request to controller

Comment: why are you worried about  that. The one who will  call your service they will be taking care those connectionTimeout/ReadTimeout. you just focus on your service.